# Check Whether the login is done or not in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please help me out how we will check in xamarin.forms whether the login is been done or not .

when ever we open the app we check the login is been done or not if login is not been done then it should move to login page or else it should move to main page.
If we logout then only it should move to login page

Same Like facebook and Gmail login

please help me out i m new to xamarin.forms in xamarin.forms we cannot use local storage also how to resolve these issue

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the answer of these solution

```
App.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = true
```

https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/LoginDemo

We can resolve these issue by setting using `IsLoggedIn` to `true`

Comment: This is a user defined property. You cannot just set this and you're done, you need to add logic as well.

Answer (score 1):

The **Application-properties** in .forms are used, to **save data persistent**.
Saved data are restored **automatically** by the app-start, but you first have to **create** them and - **important** - to **save** them.

Example for a integer value (from my app):

**In startup-code:**

```
if (!Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("iBenutzerSuchParameter"))  // Key don't exist
  { Application.Current.Properties["iBenutzerSuchParameter"] = 0; } // create it an fill a value
// overtake the setting in a global variable and convert it
   GV.iBenutzerSuchParameter = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["iBenutzerSuchParameter"]);
```

**Save the property's exlicitely:**

```
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

So... if you really want to store the "login-state" persistent and reload it by every app-start (means, that the user only have to login **one time** in "his live"), you should:
Define and create a key for store the state in your startup-code (if not exist already -> see my example code)
Maybe save the value for state "not-logged-in" and save the properties a first time.
Show your login-page
Check, if successful:
If yes, change the key to "logged-in" and save the properties.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible options:

- You can save it in a local database
- You can save it in App.Current.Properties
- You can save it in the native api's of each platform, all 3 platforms have an api to save preferences